# Info bar that drops down after a time period

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

How do get a bar drop to down from the top of the browser window after a period of time that the user has been viewing the page? Say 5 seconds. This bar would then push all content on the page down until the bar finishes appearing. The bar would be used to show a single line of text informing the user of something. And maybe a small little X on the right side of the bar to close it.

Currently this is the CSS:

```
#infobar {
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
    height: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-color: #F00;
    background-color: #9C9;
    margin-top:-16px;
}
#infobar .text {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#infobar .text a {
    color: #FAFAFA;
}
#infobar .text a:hover {
    color: #FFE2A0;
}

</style>
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="infobar">
<div class="text">
....this is the bar text....
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need Javascript/JQuery to do this, with HTML/CSS only isn't possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only HTML/CSS isn't possible, as it needs animation and time control, you'll need an additional technology, such Javascript/JQuery or Flash.

**EDIT 1**

I think the below code will do what you want.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">

#infobar {
    display:none;
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
    height: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-color: #F00;
    background: #9C9;
    margin-top:-16px;
}
#infobar .text {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font:12px arial;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#infobar .text a {
    color: #FAFAFA;
}
#infobar .text a:hover {
    color: #FFE2A0;
}

#close {
    color: red;
    float:right;
}

</style>
```

**Javascript / JQuery**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load( function() {

         setTimeout( function() {

             $("#infobar").slideToggle("fast");

         }, 5000);


        $("#close").click( function() {

            $("#infobar").slideToggle("fast");
            return false;

        });


    });

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="infobar">
    <div class="text">
        ....this is the bar text....
        <a href="#" id="close">close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @R3TRI8UTI0N, I recomend you to post other question with a resume of your HTML and CSS code. It will be complicated to write the code using the comments area. Other reason is because the Javascript/JQuery tags have big quantity of  active of users here in Stack Overflow, so your chances to get what you want are good.

Comment: I found out why the animation looks like it appears from within, the margin-top makes it do that. Though I can't figure out how to get it to stay at the top of the page without it being fixed..

edit> If I set the position to top, it pushes the page down like I want, but, then it doesn't stay at the top of the page when I scroll. I'm assuming I can't do this then?

Comment: Lol, nvm. I like the way I have it now. It's not at the top, but I instead wen't with the illusion that it appears from under the site's menu bar. Thanks!

Comment: @R3TRI8UTI0N, Yesterday i've gone away and just today i saw your new comments. If you still need help, leave a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

Very draft sample (no jquery):

Changes to CSS

```
body { 
    margin:0; padding: 10px
}
#infobar {
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
    height: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-color: #F00;
    background-color: #9C9;
    top: -30px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Minimal JavaScript

```
var topMargin = 0;

function letsgo()
{
    setTimeout("showinfo()", 5000);
}

function showinfo()
{
    document.body.style.marginTop = (topMargin++) + 'px';
    document.getElementById('infobar').style.top = (topMargin - 30) + 'px';
    if (topMargin < 30) setTimeout("showinfo()", 10);
}

function hideinfo()
{
    document.body.style.marginTop = (--topMargin) + 'px';
    document.getElementById('infobar').style.top = (topMargin - 30) + 'px';
    if (topMargin > 0) setTimeout("hideinfo()", 10);
}

window.onload = letsgo;
```

and finally some HTML

```
<div id="infobar" onclick="hideinfo()">infobar content</div>
```